# How to find source of memory leak in Node.JS App

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in Node.js/Express app.  The app dies after 3-5 days with the following log message:

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I setup a server without users connecting, and it still crashes, so I know leak is originating in the following code which runs in the background to sync api changes to the db.

```
poll(config.refreshInterval)

function poll(refreshRate) {
    return apiSync.syncDatabase()
        .then(function(){
            return wait(refreshRate)
        })
        .then(function(){
            return poll(refreshRate)
        })          
}

var wait = function wait(time) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        applog.info('waiting for %s ms..', time)
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(true)
        },time)
    })
}
```

What techniques are available for profiling the heap to find the source object(s) of what is taking all the memory?

This takes awhile to crash, so I would need something that logs and I can come back later and analyze.

Is there any option like Java's JVM flag `-XX:HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`node-memwatch`](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/).

It provides a heap diff class:

```
var hd = new memwatch.HeapDiff();
// your code here ...
var diff = hd.end();
```

It also has event emitters for leaks:

```
memwatch.on('leak', function(info) {
// look at info to find out about what might be leaking
});
```

Comment: Is there possible to detect and log variables names array indexes and code blocks?